# Data according to date in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a data like this

```
 RID      Region        StartDate                EndDate
944     Canada      2016-01-09 00:00:00.000 2016-01-16 23:59:59.000
955     Canada      2016-01-17 00:00:00.000 2016-01-24 23:59:59.000
981     Canada      2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 2016-02-08 23:59:59.000
996     Canada      2016-02-09 00:00:00.000 2016-02-16 23:59:59.000
1006    Canada      2016-01-25 00:00:00.000 2016-01-31 23:59:59.000
1020    Canada      2016-02-17 00:00:00.000 2016-02-24 23:59:59.000
1030    Canada      2016-02-25 00:00:00.000 2016-02-29 23:59:59.000
1041    Canada      2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 2016-03-08 23:59:59.000
1046    Canada      2016-03-09 00:00:00.000 2016-03-16 23:59:59.000
1062    Canada      2016-03-17 00:00:00.000 2016-03-24 23:59:59.000
1073    Canada      2016-03-24 00:00:00.000 2016-03-31 23:59:59.000
1083    Canada      2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 2016-04-08 23:59:59.000
1105    Canada      2016-04-09 00:00:00.000 2016-04-16 23:59:59.000
1118    Canada      2016-04-17 00:00:00.000 2016-04-24 23:59:59.000
1128    Canada      2016-04-25 00:00:00.000 2016-04-30 23:59:59.000
1164    Canada      2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 2016-05-08 23:59:59.000
```

now i try to select data like this

```
select * from tab1 where Region='Canada'
and StartDate ='2016-01-09 00:00:00.000'
and EndDate ='2016-01-24 23:59:59.000'
```

desired result is

```
RID      Region     StartDate                EndDate
944     Canada      2016-01-09 00:00:00.000 2016-01-16 23:59:59.000
955     Canada      2016-01-17 00:00:00.000 2016-01-24 23:59:59.000
```

but when i execute this query data is empty

any solution?

Comment: What do you expect to see? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were intending to restrict to a date *range*, but you actually restricted to two points in time instead.  Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1
WHERE Region = 'Canada' AND
      StartDate >= '2016-01-09 00:00:00.000' AND
      EndDate <= '2016-01-24 23:59:59.000'
```

Comment: What is the type of your `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns?

Comment: Are you certain of this?  The query should be returning some records, I don't know why you are getting an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab1 
WHERE Region = 'Canada'
    AND StartDate >='2016-01-09 00:00:00.000'
    AND EndDate <='2016-01-24 23:59:59.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'between' must work. I tried this. If in case it is not working, try convert function for those datetime columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1
WHERE Region = 'Canada' AND
StartDate >= convert(datetime,'2016-01-09 00:00:00.000') AND
EndDate <= convert(datetime,'2016-01-24 23:59:59.000')
```